# Python isn't catching KeyError properly

Tags: python

I've tried two different versions of the same function:

```
def position_of(self, table_name, column_name):
    positions = self.heading_positions()
    position = positions['{t}.{c}'.format(t=table_name, c=column_name)]
    return position
```

-

```
def position_of(self, table_name, column_name):
    positions = self.heading_positions()
    try:
        position = positions['{t}.{c}'.format(t=table_name, c=column_name)]
    except KeyError:
        raise RuntimeError('No heading found for {t}.{c} in import profile "{ip}"'.format(t=table_name, c=column_name, ip=self))
    return position
```

With the first version, I get the following error, which is fine:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./import.py", line 15, in <module>
    g.process()
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/generic_import.py", line 39, in process
    row.process()
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/csv_row.py", line 18, in process
    self.save()
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/csv_row.py", line 26, in save
    self.output("Phone: " + self.value('customer', 'phone'));
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/csv_row.py", line 60, in value
    print self.generic_import.import_profile.position_of(table_name, column_name)
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/import_profile.py", line 22, in position_of
    position = positions['{t}.{c}'.format(t=table_name, c=column_name)]
KeyError: 'customer.phone'
```

But the second version - the one that has the more informative error description - fails silently. Why is this?

Comment: The only way I can think of how this might happen is that you catch `RuntimeError` in some outer scope.

Comment: Try you raising a `KeyError` instead of an `RuntimeError`

Comment: @Sven +1. You can replace `raise RuntimeError(` by `raise KeyError(` and see what happens.

Comment: Can you paste a full test example of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version of `position_of` works fine for me.  I have turned it into a minimal complete program as follows:

```
class Test(object):

    def heading_positions(self):
        return {}

    def position_of(self, table_name, column_name):
        positions = self.heading_positions()
        try:
            position = positions['{t}.{c}'.format(t=table_name, c=column_name)]
        except KeyError:
            raise RuntimeError('No heading found for {t}.{c} in import profile "{ip}"'.format(t=table_name, c=column_name, ip=self))
        return position

a = Test()
a.position_of('customer', 'phone')
```

When I run this (using Python 2.6.6 on MacOS X) I get the following error message as expected:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./a.py", line 17, in <module>
    a.position_of('customer', 'phone')
  File "./a.py", line 13, in position_of
    raise RuntimeError('No heading found for {t}.{c} in import profile "{ip}"'.format(t=table_name, c=column_name, ip=self))
RuntimeError: No heading found for customer.phone in import profile "<__main__.Test object at 0x100426ad0>"
```

This shows that catching the `KeyError` and turning it into a `RuntimeError` works fine.  Does this example work for you?  As Sven already writes, a possible explanation would be if you catch `RuntimeError` but not `KeyError` somewhere in the call chain.